# Laravel database migration nullable in a lot of columns

Tags: laravel

I am writing a Laravel migration file for a table with a lot of columns, while most of them should be `nullable` (some aren't unfortunately). This leads me to write repetitive code like:

```
Schema::create('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('col_1')->nullable();
    $table->string('col_2')->nullable();
    $table->string('col_3')->nullable();
    // ...
    // (Note that col_1 etc can be different names instead of incrementing by no.)
});
```

Is there a way to set the table blueprint `nullable` by default (without needing to explicitly call `nullable()`), or assign `nullable` to all wanted columns all at once? Or is there an alternative way (preferably within the migration file) to do it?

Comment: You can always put the ColumnDefinitions in an array and loop over it calling nullable() on each. Alternatively, you could extend Blueprint via the Macroable interface. There's many ways to do this without repeating yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` class uses the [macroable](https://github.com/spatie/macroable) trait which is

> A trait to dynamically add methods to a class.

Here is how we can take advantage of this feature.

1. Add the *macro method* to a [service provider's `boot()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers#the-boot-method) (for instance: `AppServiceProvider`)

   ```
   use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
   Blueprint::macro('defaultNull', function(...$columns){
      foreach($columns as $column) {
          $column->nullable();
      }
   });
   ```
2. Use our *macro method* inside the migration class: now you can add all of the "`nullable`" columns to the `defaultNull` macro method like so:

   ```
   Schema::create('my_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->defaultNull(
           $table->string('col_1'), 
           $table->string('col_2'), 
           $table->string('col_3')
       );
   });
   ```